# Is the implication ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D_1$ and $D_2$) $\Rightarrow $ ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D=D_1\cup D_2$) true?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $D_1,D_2$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$  and $\partial D_1,\partial D_2$ are both of Lebesgue measure zero (that is to say: $D_1,D_2$ are *Jordan measurable*).
Also, let $f:D_1\cup D_2=D\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Then ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D_{1}$ and over $D_{2}$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D=D_1\cup D_2$).

The proof of above result is not difficult. The following is my question:

1. If we remove the condition "$\partial D_1,\partial D_2$ are both of Lebesgue measure zero" from  the above statement, then the result ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D=D_1\cup D_2$) $\Rightarrow$ ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D_{1}$ and over $D_{2}$) will be not correct. There is a  counterexample to  illustrate:

   Let $D=[0,1]^2$ and $D_1=\mathbb{Q}^2\cap [0,1]^2$, $D_2=[0,1]^2\setminus D_1$. $f\equiv1:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

   Obviously, $f$ is Riemann integrable over $D$. But
   $$
   f\cdot \chi _{\small{D_{1}}}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
   1 ,& \text{ as }\quad (x,y)\in D_{1}  ,\\
   0,& \text{ as }\quad (x,y)\in D_{2}.
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is not Riemann integrable over $[0,1]^2$,so $f$ is not Riemann integrable over $D_1$.
2. If we remove the condition: "$\partial D_1,\partial D_2$ are both of Lebesgue measure zero" from  the above statement, by my  intuition, ($f$ is Riemann integrable over $D_1$ and over $D_2$) $\Rightarrow$ ($f$ is  Riemann integrable over $D=D_1\cup D_2$) is also not correct !
   But until now  I have as yet neither found  a  counterexample to  illustrate my  intuition nor given a proof  to support it correct !

Comment: Please don't use italic text inside colours inside maths environments for emphasis. Your message is not clearer for using many colours and fonts.

Comment: @David Roberts: Thanks for your mention.

Comment: (2) is true. Use that a function is R integrable precisely if it is bounded and continuous a.e.

Comment: @Christian Remling:My friend,your comments may not make sure (2) is true. $int(D_{1})\cup int(D_{2})\subseteq int(D_{1}\cup D_{2})$ .Maybe some interior points of $D_{k}(k=1,2)$ at which $f$ is contionuous  will become the discontionuos points of $f $ on $D_{1}\cup D_{2}$.

Comment: @Q.L.Kwai: Express $\chi_{D_1\cup D_2}f$ in terms of $\chi_{D_j}f$.

Comment: I think I have already proved (2) is ture ! The proof is not complex.